# best way to parse dates into month blocks

Tags: c#

Given x amount of dates and the fiscal month being 1st-31st:

What's the best way to group the months. For example,

a date range of Jan 15 - Feb 15 are considered 2 items

Comment: Could you clarify more on how the data is structured. What exactly is a "date"? It it numerical i.e. 0912 = september 12th, or SEP 12 or 09/12 or what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var dateGroups = myDates.GroupBy(d => d.Month);
```

and as brought up, years would be useful

```
var dateGroups = myDates.GroupBy(d => d.Month)
    .Select(g => new {year = g.Key, monthGrouping = g.GroupBy(d => d.Month)})
    .SelectMany(a => a.monthGrouping
        .Select(g => new {a.year, month = g.Key, dates = g.AsEnumerable()}));
```

Comment: Don't forget the year (i'd guess this could be an issue with long date ranges, not sure in OP's case though)

Comment: @rod I'd follow the same pattern I did for getting the months once it is grouped by the years.